# Highlight fieldset with focused element, without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

Using only HTML & CSS and **without** using JavaScript, how would I style the fieldset around focused form inputs differently from the rest of the fieldsets? (Basically, the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17670361/1959975) but *without JavaScript*)

Below is the effect I want to achieve, currently using JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').focus(function(){ $(this).parent().addClass('jshack'); });
    $('input').blur (function(){ $(this).parent().removeClass('jshack'); });
});
```

```css
fieldset { border: 2px solid lightgray; }
fieldset.jshack { border: 2px solid black; }
input:focus { background-color: lightyellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="?" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
        <input name="text1" type="text" />
        <input name="text2" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
        <input name="text3" type="text" />
        <input name="text4" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Desired end result should be identical visually but should not use JavaScript in any way.

**UPDATE**: I am not looking for the magical CSS parent selector. I am looking for recreations of the effect with CSS trickery, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454224/3903374) which could not be posted before this was closed.

Comment: This was marked as duplicate before I had a chance to post a way to simulate the effect.  I've added my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29454224/3903374

Comment: If this gets reopened, I'll move my answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without javascript as there is no way in CSS to target the parent of an element... at least not yet. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/2126792).

---

**Edit: I was wrong, Rick Hitchcock has come up with a very nice and simple workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454224/2126792.**

Comment: I've decided to reword the question to ask for recreations instead of the magical CSS parent selector, but I had already voted on this answer.

Comment: You're not "wrong" at all.  The fieldset itself cannot be styled based on a focused input.  I simply came up with a way to simulate the effect.